# how to customize a getitem in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want a custom class getitem method. I don't want to use built-in `__getitem__`, because `__getitem__` has another use. 
  for example:

```py
    class MyClass(object):
        def __init__(self,):
            self.a = [6,2,3,4,5]
            self.b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
        def __getitem__(self, index)
            return self.a[index] #this method has another use
        def __mygetitem__(self, special_index):
            index_b = self.a.index(special_index)
            return self.b[index_b]

    c1 = MyClass()
    c1.mygetitem[3]
```

I don't want to use a function to solve the problem like this: `c1.myfunction(3)`
  maybe I need to know how class method convert `[]` to a function.

Comment: Is there a *reason* you don't want to simply define a method (or even more simply, just access `self.b` directly)?

Comment: actually, special_index is not the index of self.b, it will convert to self.b index by a function, for example:

Comment: index_b = self.a.index(special_index);                                                                                              return self.b[index_b]

Comment: I just want to let code look beautiful. special_index is another index of self.b, the code looks beautiful if use c1.xxx[] than c1.xxx()

Answer (score 0):

Make `mygetitem` a property that just returns a reference to `self.b`.

```
@property
def mygetitem(self):
    return self.b
```

Really, all you are doing is making `mygetitem` another name for `b`, which you could do from `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.a = [1,2,3,4,5]
    self.b = self.mygetitem = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

But the read-only property makes it harder to inadvertently break the "link" between `b` and `mygetitem`.

Comment: i didn't explain the problem clearly before, so i renew the problem. Looking forward to your reply

Comment: This doesn't change my answer. `[]` is applied to the value of the *attribute*, not the instance of `MyClass`, so all you can do is have `c1.mygetitem` evaluate to something which provides `__getitem__`.